# JS Function Help - No errors but won't show up

Tags: javascript, function

I'm not sure where I went wrong. I'm not getting any errors in the console and nothing is showing up on the page.

If anyone could take a look and maybe see something small I missed.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var myStage;
      
  function init(){
    myStage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
    drawStar(50);
    myStage.update();
  }
        
  function drawStar(num){
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
    
      var polygon = new createjs.Shape();
      var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      polygon.graphics.beginFill(color);
      polygon.graphics.moveTo(20, 80).lineTo(80, 80).lineTo(50, 120).lineTo(20, 80).lineTo(50, 40).lineTo(80, 80);
    
      var shape = new createjs.Shape();
      var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(20, 80, 3);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(80, 80, 3);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(50, 120, 3);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(50, 40, 3);
    
      var lines = new createjs.Shape();
      var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      lines.graphics.beginStroke(color);
      lines.graphics.moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(50, -5000).moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(-5000, 80).moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(10000, 80).moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(50, 10000);
      
      var container = new createjs.Container();
      container.addChild(lines,polygon,shape);
      
      container.x = Math.random()*1024;
      container.y = Math.random()*960;
      container.rotation = Math.random()*360;
      
      myStage.addChild(container);
    }
  }
//-->
</script>
<title>Generative Art</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1500" height="1500">Sorry. You need an HTML5 compatible browser to see this.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question (not as an image)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have to actually call one of those functions. Defining a function doesn't run it. Put `init(); drawStar();` at the end of your script

Comment: Thank you, posted the code - maybe I'm mistaken but I called the function right about myStage.update();. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: That's inside your init function. You never called your init function.

Comment: Oh, I think that's it... that's what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have written the functions but they are never called.

You have to call them so that the code inside them can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you are declaring the functions but never call them.
Call init like this:

```
<script>
  var myStage;

  function init(){
    myStage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
    drawStar(50);
    myStage.update();
  }

  function drawStar(num){
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){

      var polygon = new createjs.Shape();
      var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      polygon.graphics.beginFill(color);
      polygon.graphics.moveTo(20, 80).lineTo(80, 80).lineTo(50, 120).lineTo(20, 80).lineTo(50, 40).lineTo(80, 80);

      var shape = new createjs.Shape();
      var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(20, 80, 3);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(80, 80, 3);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(50, 120, 3);
      shape.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(50, 40, 3);

      var lines = new createjs.Shape();
      var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      lines.graphics.beginStroke(color);
      lines.graphics.moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(50, -5000).moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(-5000, 80).moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(10000, 80).moveTo(50, 80).lineTo(50, 10000);

      var container = new createjs.Container();
      container.addChild(lines,polygon,shape);

      container.x = Math.random()*1024;
      container.y = Math.random()*960;
      container.rotation = Math.random()*360;

      myStage.addChild(container);
    }
    init();
  }
//-->
```